How to add an inline item after Text component's `numberOfLines` truncation in React Native
I want a wrapped text that ends with an image icon, and tried the following.
    <Text>
        <Text
            numberOfLines={2}
            ellipsizeMode="tail"
            >
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab quasi in dolor dolore recusandae ullam numquam labore sunt illo. Repellat in sed sit, pariatur voluptate distinctio! Perspiciatis inventore pariatur incidunt.
        </Text>
        <Image source={source} />
    </Text>

The outer wrapper <Text /> is to ensure that the <Image /> icon stays inline with the text.
I was hoping it would look like below:
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Ab quasi in dolor dolore recusandae ullam... <Image />

However, adding the outer <Text /> seems to have removed the effect of numberOfLines and I get the full text instead:
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Ab quasi in dolor dolore recusandae ullam numquam labore
    sunt illo. Repellat in sed sit, pariatur voluptate
    distinctio! Perspiciatis inventore pariatur incidunt. <Image />

Is it possible to achieve both the truncation via numberOfLines and the inline <Image /> at the end?
Thanks,


you can use view component in order to solve the issue

 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="tail" style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab quasi in
          dolor dolore recusandae ullam numquam labore sunt illo. Repellat in
          sed sit, pariatur voluptate distinctio! Perspiciatis inventore
          pariatur incidunt.
        </Text>
        <Image source={require('./assets/snack-icon.png')} />
      </View>


I tried it, but the  won't stay inline with the text, it becomes a separate component beside the text.

I have created an example:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  TextLayoutLine,
  Text,
  TextStyle,
  StyleProp,
  TextProps,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';

export interface IReadMoreTextProps extends TextProps {
  style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
  numberOfLines?: number;
  children: string;
  appendComponent?: JSX.Element;
}

interface TextProperties {
  length: number;
  isTruncatedText: boolean;
}

export function TextInlneImage({
  style,
  numberOfLines = 1,
  children,
  appendComponent,
  ...props
}: IReadMoreTextProps) {
  const [text, setText] = useState<TextProperties>({
    length: 0,
    isTruncatedText: false,
  });

  function handleOnTextLayout(textLayoutLines: TextLayoutLine[]) {
    let textLength = 0;
    if (textLayoutLines.length > numberOfLines) {
      for (var line = 0; line < numberOfLines; line++) {
        textLength += textLayoutLines[line].text.length;
      }
      setText({ length: textLength, isTruncatedText: true });
      return;
    }
    setText({ length: children.length, isTruncatedText: false });
  }

  return (
    <>
      {/** 
        iOS requires element to be drawn for getting needed lines
       */}
      {Platform.OS === 'ios' && (
        <Text
          style={{ height: 0 }}
          onTextLayout={({ nativeEvent: { lines } }) => {
            if (text.length > 0) {
              return;
            }
            handleOnTextLayout(lines);
          }}>
          {children}
        </Text>
      )}
      <Text
        style={style}
        numberOfLines={text.length === 0 ? numberOfLines : 0}
        onTextLayout={({ nativeEvent: { lines } }) => {
          if (text.length > 0) {
            return;
          }
          handleOnTextLayout(lines);
        }}
        {...props}>
        {text.isTruncatedText &&
        props.ellipsizeMode === 'tail' &&
        text.length !== 0
          ? `${children.slice(0, text.length - 20).trim()}...`
          : children}
        {text.isTruncatedText && <Text style={style}>{appendComponent}</Text>}
      </Text>
    </>
  );
}


